# INNODB and mysql PDO driver lock in share mode

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, innodb

With INNODB you can add to your query `LOCK IN SHARE MODE;` so that other users can still read but not update untill the user that is editing is finished.

My current PDO function in PHP currently looks like:

```
//$this->db is a PDO connection to the MYSQL innodb database.
try 
    {
    $this->db->beginTransaction();
    $tmp = $this->db->prepare($query);  

    $tmp->execute($arr);
    $this->last_id = $this->db->lastInsertId();
    $this->db->commit();
    return $this->last_id;
    }
catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
    $this->db->rollBack();
    return $ex->getMessage();
    }
```

Is there an PDO driver function setting to set it in share mode? if so how? The only things I find have no answers to them and the documentation isn't really clear either.
Or should I add it simply to the query string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create your query to mach the MySQL syntax and that's all, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM parent WHERE NAME = 'Jones' LOCK IN SHARE MODE
```

Just append the LOCK IN SHARE MODE to the query string.

Comment: So, this will not hamper the transaction functions of the PDO connection? And will the lock be released after the commit? or do I need to release it via a query?

Comment: Yes the transaction functions will work and the lock will be released after the transaction is ended.